# Spring Data JPA Specification groupBy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

sorry for my english first.

i want use jpa to groupby, like : select scrip, dustup, count(*) from data flow group by scrip, dstip.
so, write these code:

```
public class DataflowSpec {
    public static Specification<Dataflow> search(final String[] group, final String[] sort, final String[] desc) {
        return new Specification<Dataflow>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Dataflow> root1, CriteriaQuery<?> query1, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = builder.createQuery(Tuple.class);

                Root<Dataflow> root = query.from(Dataflow.class);


                query.multiselect(root.get("srcip"), root.get("dstip"), builder.count(root));

                query.groupBy(root.get("srcip"), root.get("dstip"));

                query.orderBy(builder.desc(root.get("srcip").as(BigInteger.class)));
                return query.getRestriction();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

but , SQL log is:
Hibernate:

```
select
    count(dataflow0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
from
    Dataflow dataflow0_
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    dataflow0_.id as id1_2_,
    dataflow0_.byteall as byteall2_2_,
    dataflow0_.bytedn as bytedn3_2_,
    dataflow0_.byteup as byteup4_2_,
    dataflow0_.dstip as dstip5_2_,
    dataflow0_.dstport as dstport6_2_,
    dataflow0_.engieid as engieid7_2_,
    dataflow0_.flag as flag8_2_,
    dataflow0_.netid as netid9_2_,
    dataflow0_.pkgall as pkgall10_2_,
    dataflow0_.pkgdn as pkgdn11_2_,
    dataflow0_.pkgup as pkgup12_2_,
    dataflow0_.protocolid as protoco17_2_,
    dataflow0_.rtt as rtt13_2_,
    dataflow0_.srcip as srcip14_2_,
    dataflow0_.srcport as srcport15_2_,
    dataflow0_.updatetime as updatet16_2_ 
from
    Dataflow dataflow0_ limit ?
```

so, how to resolve it? thanks!

Comment: Did you try it with the JPQL ?

Comment: so you return the Predicate for the WHERE clause (to somewhere) ... and what happens to the SELECT clause part?

Comment: no, i just want use specification.

Comment: Stockton. i want SELECT use two field:srcip, dstip.but it return all field.

Answer (score 3):

For people still looking for how to apply "group by" in Spring jpa Specification, you can use something like the following snippet:

```
...
private Dataflow dataflowFilter;

@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Dataflow> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    Predicate predicate = cb.conjunction();
    predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.equal(root.get("id"), dataflowFilter.getId()));
    ...
    cq.groupBy(root.get("id"));
    ...
    return predicate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve spring data `group by` by `specification`, just follow
[section 2.6][1]  or [section 3.6][2] for version before or after 2.0. For single repository manipulation, the two versions have identical solution. For the *all * repository solution, before 2.0 use [customized factory bean][3], while after 2.0 this factory bean manipulation is omitted.

```
public Map<AlarmMsg.AlarmLevel, Long> testSpecification(String neId) {

    SingularAttribute attribute = AlarmData_.isClear;
    Specification<Object> where = Specification.where(
        (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get(attribute), false)
    );

    final Map<AlarmMsg.AlarmLevel, Long> result = alarmDataRepository.groupAndCount(AlarmData_.alarmLevel, where );
    return result;
}
```

repository:

```
public interface AlarmDataRepository extends JpaRepository<AlarmData, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<AlarmData>, CustomizedGroupCountRepository {
```

Fragment repository and its implementation:

```
public interface CustomizedGroupCountRepository {
    Map<AlarmMsg.AlarmLevel, Long> groupAndCount(SingularAttribute singularAttribute, Specification where);
}

public class CustomizedGroupCountRepositoryImpl implements CustomizedGroupCountRepository {
    private final EntityManager entityManager;


    public CustomizedGroupCountRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        Assert.notNull(entityManager, "EntityManager must not be null!");
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<AlarmMsg.AlarmLevel, Long> groupAndCount(SingularAttribute singularAttribute, Specification where) {
        final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
        final Root<AlarmData> root = query.from(AlarmData.class);
        final Path<AlarmMsg.AlarmLevel> expression = root.get(singularAttribute);
        query.multiselect(expression, criteriaBuilder.count(root));
        query.select(criteriaBuilder.tuple(expression, criteriaBuilder.count(root)));
        query.where(where.toPredicate(root, query, criteriaBuilder));
        query.groupBy(expression);
        final List<Tuple> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
        return resultList.stream()
            .collect(toMap(
                t -> t.get(0, AlarmMsg.AlarmLevel.class),
                t -> t.get(1, Long.class))
            );
    }
}
```

The main difference between one-for-all-repository and one-for-single-repository is, in one-for-single-repository case, it can access the real entity class, like `User` in spring reference document. So that you don't need to use generic types to refer an any-typed entity, while in one-for-all-repository case, the implementation of the customized method uses generic types, and its class information could (or must) be gained from an injected `JpaEntityInformation` as stated in both section 3.6.
[1]: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour
[2]: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior
[3]: https://jeroenbellen.com/spring-data-extending-the-jpa-specification-executor/

Comment: 'query.multiselect(expression, criteriaBuilder.count(root));' 
'query.select(criteriaBuilder.tuple(expression, criteriaBuilder.count(root)));'

                               Why these two lines, when just one would suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Specification doesn't support groupBy. 
SimpleJpaRepository replaced query.select/multiselect by query.select(root)

Comment: `Specification` is used for `where` part. `CriteriaQuery` is used for `select`